# securesocial error when login using localhost/login in playframework

Tags: playframework

I use securesocial with the default view, after start up the play, and I browser the url of

localhost:9000/login

My hope is that the url will show me the login page, however it show the error of

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper$]
```

I debug the issue, the call stack is like the following:

```
securesocial_2.10/srcs/securesocial_2.10-2.1.3-sources.jar!/securesocial/controllers/LoginPage.scala
 Ok(use[TemplatesPlugin].getLoginPage(request, UsernamePasswordProvider.loginForm))

securesocial_2.10/srcs/securesocial_2.10-2.1.3-sources.jar!/securesocial/controllers/TemplatesPlugin.scala
    securesocial.views.html.login(form, msg)

play_2.10/srcs/play_2.10-2.2.2-sources.jar!/play/api/mvc/Action.scala
 case e: LinkageError => throw new RuntimeException(e)
```

What's the problem here,the error stack in IDEA is like the following:

! @6in8cm53j - Internal server error, for (GET) [/login] ->

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper$]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:165) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper$
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:314) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:107) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class securesocial.core.providers.utils.RoutesHelper$
    at securesocial.views.html.provider$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(provider.template.scala:50) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at securesocial.views.html.provider$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(provider.template.scala:42) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at securesocial.views.html.provider$.apply(provider.template.scala:42) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at securesocial.views.html.login$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(login.template.scala:79) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at securesocial.views.html.login$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(login.template.scala:71) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
[error] application -
```

Comment: What you set in play plugins file? Erase anything related to securesocial